# Military sci-fi book: humans forced to demilitarize by alien race(s?), warship with efficient distributed AI system reconditioned for exploration

Tags: story-identification, books, pirates

Things I remember about this book:

- Humans had been forced by alien race(s) to either demilitarize or severely cut back on military to join galactic community
- Unknown aliens attacking in Solar System
- An expedition is launched on a reconditioned warship. I definitely remember that the ship had a distributed AI system, which humans were apparently very good at as compared to the other galactic civilizations
- There was an FTL system in general use, the author has one of the characters highlight a long string of numbers as coordinates involved with this system
- Coordinates where raiding aliens are originating from are discovered. Previously mentioned expedition goes through coordinates, lands at the bottom of an unidentified ocean
- Possibly galactic representatives on expedition
- Ending was definitely a cliffhanger, but I couldn't find a sequel at the time

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like ["Startide Rising"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/234501.Startide_Rising) (1983) by David Brin.

Humans join Galatic Community. Expedition is pursued by aliens, Earth is under attack. They land at the bottom of an ocean because much of the crew is uplifted Dolphins.  They sneak out by hiding their ship inside a crashed alien ship (the aliens are fighting each other to get at what the humans have discovered).  They escape the system, but the situation isn't really resolved as the chase is still going on.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is it. It does sound quite similar, but the expedition in the book I was looking for has to abandon ship,  because the hull can't take the extreme pressure. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Parts of it sound a bit like *Brightness Reef* (1995), which is one of David Brin's *Uplift* books.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25059.Brightness_Reef):

> The planet Jijo is forbidden to settlers, its ecology protected by guardians of the Five Galaxies.  But over the centuries it has been resettled, populated by refugees of six intelligent races.  Together they have woven a new society in the wilderness, drawn together by their fear of Judgment Day, when the Five Galaxies will discover their illegal colony.  Then a strange starship arrives on Jijo.  Does it bring the long-dreaded judgment, or worse--a band of criminals willing to destroy the six races of Jijo in order to cover their own crimes?

Comment: I don't think this is it, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Parts of this remind me of Charles Sheffield's novel [The Nimrod Hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nimrod_Hunt) (also published in altered form as The Mind Pool).

Points of similarity:

Earth is part of a confederation with several alien species, all of whom are far less aggressive than humans, and **who discourage weapons development, etc.**

Due to a crisis (a weaponized cybernetic creature (developed by humans for defense) escapes, killing many), **a multispecies expedition** is sent to find where the creature is hiding.

FTL exists, and requires a **lengthy exact numerical address** to work

Comment: I seem to remember that The Mind Pool had the initial exploration ship materialize at the bottom of an alien ocean

Comment: I only read the Nimrod Hunt version I think.  You could be right about the other

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of "Battlefield Earth" (1982) by L. Ron Hubbard, not, as far as I know, related to the series of the same name. It's a big really thick book and it has all those elements you mentioned...

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/769658.Battlefield_Earth):

> Earth has been dominated for 1,000 years by an alien invader—and man is an endangered species. From the handful of surviving humans a courageous leader emerges—Jonnie Goodboy Tyler, who challenges the invincible might of the alien Psychlo empire in a battle of epic scale, danger and intrigue with the fate of the Earth and of the universe in the tenuous balance.

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked the wiki, and that doesn't seem to be what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!